# Error deploying BizTalk Application - Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2009

Any idea why I would be getting this Access Denied Exception?

I'm deploying a very basic BizTalk 2009 project from Visual Studio.

> error DEPLOY: 
>      Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
>
> error DEPLOY:    at Microsoft.BizTalk.Gac.Fusion.IAssemblyCache.InstallAssembly(AssemblyCacheInstallFlag flags, String manifestFilePath, FusionInstallReference referenceData)
>          at Microsoft.BizTalk.Gac.Gac.InstallAssembly(String assemblyPathname, Boolean force)
>   at Microsoft.BizTalk.Deployment.BizTalkAssembly.GacInstall(String assemblyLocation)
>   at Microsoft.BizTalk.Deployment.BizTalkAssembly.PrivateDeploy(String server, String database, String assemblyPathname, String applicationName)
>   at Microsoft.BizTalk.Deployment.BizTalkAssembly.Deploy(Boolean redeploy, String server, String database, String assemblyPathname, String group, String applicationName, ApplicationLog log)
>
> error DEPLOY: Unspecified exception: "
>   Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))"
>
> Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
>
> error DEPLOY: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
>
> : PerformingEndChangeRequestsWithRollBack
>
> error DEPLOY: Failed to add resource(s). Change requests failed for some resources. BizTalkAssemblyResourceManager failed to complete end type change request. Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

Comment: This same solution works for BizTalk 2010

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use Run As -> Administrator for Visual Studio.  You must have Admin privileges to deploy BizTalk assemblies (since they deploy to the GAC).

Comment: Thanks. I'm new to Biztalk, Visual Studio, and .net. This solved my problem!